# Arranging DIV menu on the page

Tags: css, html

As you can from the link below, there are menu, body and a shape drawn in CSS

But  can't arrange this menu properly like

```
____________
|  M E N U
| |      |
| |      |
| |      |
| |      |
| |      |
| |      |
| |______|
|___________
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="hr">
    <li class="hr"> <img src="Logo.jpg" draggable="false"> </li>
    <li class="hr"> <img src="left.jpg" draggable="false"> </li>
    <li class="hr"> <img src="Home.jpg" draggable="false" onmouseover="this.src='Home_Hover.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='Home.jpg';"> </li>
    <li class="hr"> <img src="Blank1.jpg" draggable="false"> </li>
    <li class="hr"> <img src="Services.jpg" draggable="false" onmouseover="this.src='Services_hover.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='Services.jpg';"> </li>
    <li class="hr"> <img src="Blank2.jpg" draggable="false"> </li>
    <li class="hr"> <img src="work.jpg" draggable="false" onmouseover="this.src='work_hover.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='work.jpg';">  </li>
    <li class="hr"> <img src="Blank3.jpg" draggable="false"> </li>
    <li class="hr"> <img src="About.jpg" draggable="false" onmouseover="this.src='about_hover.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='about.jpg';"> </li>
    <li class="hr"> <img src="Right.jpg" draggable="false"> </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.hr { margin: 0; padding: 0px; } 
ul.hr li { display: inline; padding: 0px; }
```

Thank you !

Comment: That's not much to go on...please create a JSFiddle

Comment: Menu must be agganged in center without any spaces between images. Thank you !

Comment: So what CSS do you have at the moment? People here won't just write the code for you, you at least need to show something you've tried

Comment: Forgot to insert it, sorry      ul.hr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
   }

   ul.hr li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px; 
   }

Comment: If you don't want any spaces between the images,  then why have you added spaces? Remove the whitespace around each image tag for a start

Comment: Here is http://jsfiddle.net/K7JDs/5/

Comment: Please see the updated answer I've provided below

Comment: wickywills  thank's a lot. That is ixactly what i've needed. It's actually my first try on a web site, so thatnk you once again

Comment: No problem - good luck finishing it off! I think it could be a nice looking site :) You'll learn a lot along the way. Would you also be able to mark the answer as "accepted" if it helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see **[here for updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K7JDs/8/)**

I've set a width on the UL of 1200px, and added `display:block` on the images to remove any space added by browser defaults.